# Does my toddler need a bed?

Tags: dream-house-days

I know that the adults and students sleep in beds. The babies sleep in cribs. Do the toddlers need a specific bed? Right now they just sleep wherever on the floors, and no one has yelled at me to get them proper beds. Do I need to?

Comment: Interesting.  There is a Toddler stage, but the help file ignores it entirely.  They won't use a crib or a bed.  I suppose I could try adding a pet bed and seeing what happens, but I don't think Toddlers use beds at all.

Comment: I usually just drop them on the floor somewhere...oh you mean a video game.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Children have two states: Baby, and Child.  Each state lasts a year.  Babies use cribs, as you said.  Children on up can use beds.

I found out through observing my married couple, that Beds will get used on a first-come, first-serve basis.  Since only a single person can use each bed, you would theoretically need at least three beds.

I can't find anything that says kids, or even spouses need beds.  There may not be any detriment to not giving them a bed, but each one increases rent of the apartment, so it might be a good thing to add it, if the space and tenant wealth can support it.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as they are toddlers for such a short time they aren't really that important on this game, so I'm pretty sure they just sleep on the floor. They may add in toddler beds but so far they just go on the floor :)

Answer (score -1):

I have found that because the toddler stage only lasts about a few minutes,or 'a day', that they don't use a bed.I have tried the pet bed but that didn't work.I hope this helps!

In short-
Toddlers don't have beds.

Answer (score -1):

The toddlers don't use beds when the game was created they only added the toddlers to make the stages realistic 
    in short toddlers don't need bed